# Function Writes to DB when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, sql

I have a Timer with an interval of 1 second. Every second I call this function to check the OS's last input time. If the time returned by the function is over 600 (10 minutes) I call another function to write stuff to a DB.

The problem comes in here, instead of inserting one row into the DB, the function will create many records within the same second. I'm not sure why this is happening. It doesn't happen when debugging.

```
public void elapsedGetIdleCount(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        uint result = GetLastInputTime();

        if (result >= 600)
        {
            result = 0;
            tmrIdle.Stop();

            try
            {
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load(@"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/3CXPhone for Windows/3CXPhone.xml");
                var element = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Accounts/Profiles/Profile/AuthUser");
                var extension = element.InnerText.ToString();

                SetQueueStatus("LoggedOUT", "Inactivity");

                DialogResult mb = MessageBox.Show("You have been Logged Out of the Queues due to inactivity!", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

                if (mb == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    ChangeQueueStatusColor();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

public void SetQueueStatus(string status, string eventDesc)
    {
        try
        { 
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(@"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/AppData/Roaming/3CXPhone for Windows/3CXPhone.xml");
            var element = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("Accounts/Profiles/Profile/AuthUser");
            var extension = element.InnerText.ToString();

            string conString = "Data Source = lewcomp1\\COMPLIANCE; Initial Catalog = ComplianceData; Integrated Security = True";

            using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand myCMD = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    myCMD.Connection = myCon;
                    myCMD.CommandText = "UPDATE eData SET QueueStatus = '" + status + "', Extension = '" + extension + "' WHERE UserName LIKE '" + lblUserName.Text + "';";
                    SqlDataReader myReader;

                    myCon.Open();
                    myReader = myCMD.ExecuteReader();
                    myReader.Read();
                    myCon.Close();

                    myCMD.CommandText = "INSERT INTO eQueueData (Date_Time, UserName, Extension, EventID, EventDesc) VALUES ('" + DateTime.Now + "','" + lblUserName.Text + "','" + extension + "','" + status + "','" + eventDesc + "');";
                    myCon.Open();
                    myReader = myCMD.ExecuteReader();
                    myReader.Read();
                    myCon.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

static uint GetLastInputTime()
    {
        uint idleTime = 0;
        LASTINPUTINFO lastInputInfo = new LASTINPUTINFO();
        lastInputInfo.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(lastInputInfo);
        lastInputInfo.dwTime = 0;

        uint envTicks = (uint)Environment.TickCount;

        if (GetLastInputInfo(ref lastInputInfo))
        {
            uint lastInputTick = lastInputInfo.dwTime;

            idleTime = envTicks - lastInputTick;
        }
        return ((idleTime > 0) ? (idleTime / 1000) : 0);
    }
```

[image: Screen Shot of DB Entries]

Comment: Your best bet is to debug and put a break point on the insert into the DB and see if it gets called 3 times. Your function may be called on different threads.

Comment: Just possibility : are you subscribing to elapsed timer event 3 times ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll debug when I get home now. No I've only attached timer to event once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I'm quite sure, that this routine is called several times. Possible reasons:

- multiple abonnement of event
- several places call this independently

Place a break point and observe the call stack...

One idea might be to use either a static Flag to mark, that the process of logging out due to inactivity is running and refuse to enter the procedure again.

Another idea was to set a value to your `lastInputTick` to ensure, that the next call will get an answer below 600...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I haven't made use of a static flag. would you mind further explaining them?

Comment: Well, flags are always a bit ugly and something one should avoid, but: As you are processing a forced logout, I'd think this is OK in this case. In the place where you have your `static uint GetLastInputTime()` you can place a `public static bool ForcedShutdown`. When you enter your code block after having checked for `>=600`, you set this flag to true. And in your `GetLastInputTime` you use something like `if(ForcedShutdown) return 0;`. You might set this to false in a `finally` block to deal with possible errors...

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. I will test this as soon as I can.